# How to run a PHP function in backgroung, after every 'bulk mysql insert'?

Tags: php, mysql, parallel-processing

In my PHP application users inserts large amount of data at once and i need to process it. Since the processing is so much time consuming, i need the application to work in following scenario.

1. Insert Data into MySql Database and user get a notification saying
   data inserted for processing
2. Start a background PHP function which process the newly data. ( Data is processed by sending it to another server which provides API ) . The background function should start running exactly after the bulk insertion is done.

Is there any functionality in PHP that can be used as solution for above problem ?

Comment: Take a look at php-resque: https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque

Comment: get the data, send the notification and then start a cron job on the backed, isn't that fine?

Comment: @Oliwol Any tutorial available to use php-resque in a codeigniter project

Comment: php-resque says "Set QUEUE env var containing the list of queues to work". how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, as soon as the data is inserted you can send a response to the user and after that you can execute what ever code you want, below is an example.

```
$this->insert($data);
ob_start();
ignore_user_abort(true);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$len = strlen($content);
header('Connection: close');
header("Content-Length: $len");
header("Status: I will continue doing what I do you please get out");
flush();
$this->procesNewData();
```

This will work, cheers hope it helps, if it does like it mate ;)

Comment: what happens here if the user close the browser or open any other page immediately after submitting the data ?.

Comment: before inserting the data if he closes data wont be inserted and nothing gets executed, after inserting if he closes then, procesNewData() function will get executed, if you want to insert even after the user closes the browser then just put ignore_user_abort(false) in the first line, that is all